# Persist property value during GET & POST ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to obtain value of a property `(UserUniqueId)` stored during Get operation.

```
public ActionResult Create(int uniqueId = -1)
{
    w = new Work { UserUniqueId = uniqueId };
    //todo: how to pass uniqueId while rendering view. such that must receive it back during post.
    return View(w);
}
```

View doest not populate / update this value..
I need to access `UserUniqueId` for database save operation.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Work work)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Set uniqueId, Set UserId
            int userId = WebSecurity.HasUserId ? WebSecurity.CurrentUserId : -1;
            work.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            //Need previously stored uniqueId here.
            work.UserUniqueId = //How do I obtain this value here.
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(work);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the value in an `<input type="hidden" />` in your form.  (`@Html.Hidden()` from a model property)

You can then get it as a property of the model (or as a separate parameter to the method) in your POST action.

Answer (score 0):

In the view, I assume you've `@Model` set as Work then you can create hidden field like

```
 <%= Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.UserUniqueId) %>
```